# Why do my gems install into the wrong folder?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I installed Ruby and Rails via RVM, but using "`gem install something`", the console tries to install into `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8` directory.

Do I still need this Ruby dir?

Comment: what system is it? did you used a ruby? show `gem env`

Answer (score 2):

You are still using the default Ruby.  You need to activate RVM for your shell session.  See item 2 at the below:

http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

(and no I wouldn't delete the original Ruby dir)

Comment: myusername$ source ~/.bash_profile
-bash: user$: command not found

Comment: The content of my .bash_profile:

user$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: It looks like you included the "user$" from the rvm docs example.  Take that out.  Also, the echo was just assuming you were going to put the commands into the file from the shell.  So take that out, too.  It should start with "[[" (without the quotes).  Here is the line from my bash_profile: [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

Comment: If you're still having issues let me know what the output is if you type "rvm list" and "rvm use default" (the latter should at least get rvm loaded for that session)

Answer (score 0):

You have to direct your shell to use RVM and the Ruby version. You can do so by issuing the following command:

```
 rvm use *ruby version (example: 1.8.7)*
```

Or, if you have created a gemset for particular project:

```
 rvm use *ruby version (example: 1.8.7)*@*my_gem_set*
```